# How to get user details who accessed azure blob container from .log files in $logs directory

Tags: azure, storage, databricks

I am trying to find out user details who accessed a blob storage in an Azure container
Can I find out details from .log files in $logs directory or is there any other way ?

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have Azure AD authentication and configured [2.0 logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-log-format#log-entry-format-20) already, in that case you can use **`UserPrincipalName`** column to identify the user and parse the column with JSON **`AuthorizationDetail.action`** to identify the action of the user on storage either write,read etc

Answer (score 0):

Storage Analytics [log format version 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Storage-Analytics-Log-Format#log-entry-format-10) has the information, which needs [OAuth 2.0 token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory#use-oauth-access-tokens-for-authentication) which must be provided by Azure Active Directory. You must make sure you call the Storage operations with OAuth Tokens before you start.

Or by generating the [SAS(Shared Access Signature)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview) Token which is an URl that grants restricted access to the Azure Storage resources, by distributing the shared access signature  which can be for a specific period of time.